# How to change values of a class instance with methods?

Tags: java

I have a class named Time with attributes Hour, Min and Sec:

```
class Time {
  private int Hour;
  private int Min;
  private int Sec;
}
```

a constructor:

```
public Time(int h, int m, int s){
    Hour = h;
    Min = m;
    Sec = s;
}
```

and an instance time1 of the Time class:

```
Time time1 = new Time(12, 34, 52);
```

I wanted to create a method inside  that will sum to the Hour attribute of time1 instance and return me the result in Time type, but when I try this it gives me the "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Time" error:

```
     public Time Add(int hrs){
     return Hour + hrs;
 }
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: because your method needs to return a type of int, not Time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to instanciate a new `Time` object

```
public Time Add(int hrs){
    return new Time(this.Hour + hrs, this.Min, this.Sec);
}
```

---

Also java naming convention, is lowerCamelCase for methods and attributs so `hour, min, sec` and `add`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for an instance method in `Time` class however, implementations may vary:

- Mutate inner state of `Time` instance -- similar to a setter, returning reference to `this`

```java
// mutate current instance:
class Time {
    public Time addHours(int hours) {
        this.Hours += hours;
        return this;
    }
}

Usage:
Time time1 = new Time(12, 34, 52);
time1.addHours(2); // time1.Hour becomes 14
```

- Immutable implementation -- create new instance of time using its `Hour` and `hours`

```java
// mutate current instance:
class Time {
    public Time addHours(int hours) {
        return new Time(Hour + hours, Min, Sec);
    }
}

// Usage:
Time time1 = new Time(12, 34, 52);
Time time2 = time1.addHours(2); // time1.Hour remains 14
```

Answer (score 0):

In the method return type you put Time but you are returning Hour(Type=int) + hrs(Type=int) which is their sum and it is also of type int. That's why you are getting the Type mismatch error